# Limit with variable: non-defined expression

Tags: calculus, limits

Decide whether or not the following functions have a limit at the indicated point

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow0}\frac{1}{x^2}$$

$x=0 $
It is not defined....try from left to right

Comment: One could say $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}(1/x^2)=\infty$. Contrast this with  $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}(1/x)$; which isn't defined, even in the infinite sense.

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't explain the left to right meaning

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answers your question.

If limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ exists then $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0_-} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0_+} f(x)$ exists and also
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0_+} f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0_-} f(x)$$
In your case that's:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0_+} \frac{1}{x^2}= \infty=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0_-} \frac{1}{x^2}$$

So your limit exists: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x^2}=\infty$$

As David Mitra suggested you can compare it to $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x}$ where one sided limits are not equal.